# Populate a vector that contains objects from multiple derived classes from csv file

Tags: c++, csv

Let's say I have 2 different classes derived from a base class - `A` being the base class, `B` and `C` the derived classes.

```cpp
class A {
  virtual ~A () = default;

  int m;
};
        
class B : public A {
  std::string n;
  std::string p;
};
        
class C : public A {
  double x;
  std::string y;
};
```

If I want to populate a vector using a CSV file, how would the compiler realize which type of object each line should be?

Let's say I have a CSV file looking like this:

```
1, car, foo             
2, 2.3, bar
3, 1.0, chop
```

The first line is a `B` object, the second and last lines are `C` objects.

Do I need to use a bunch of `if` statements?

Should I create a different file for each object type?

I don't really have code of my own regarding this, because I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You're asking the compiler as to how to differentiate, but I can't differentiate them.  What makes `B` fit the first line,  and `C` the second and third line?

Comment: how do you know which type of object needs to be created for each line?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I changed the B class so that it's somewhat more clear i hope.

Comment: What if the string is actually `"2.3"` and not a value?  All of those questions being asked  are leading to the answer of "you need to write the code to do this".  The compiler cannot help you.

Comment: read the whole line, parse it, implement some logic to decide what it is. There is no magic shortcut.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ok, thank you, i thought there was more to it than just that

Comment: if feasible I'd add a `"C"` or `"B"` in front of the line in the code that writes the file. I mean whoever writes it should know if they write a number or a string. In general de-/serialization in C++ can be arbitrarily complicated when done from scratch. You might consider to use a library

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i just thought there was more to it than just reading the whole line and parsing it and then implementing the logic, i didn't formulate the question very clearly

Comment: Does it have to be CSV? If not, use JSON, perhaps.